# Как реализовать многоуровневое меню в консоли на Python 3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, curses

Есть задача для решения которой мне необходимо реализовать интерфейс в консоли используя Python. Целевая платформа Win 7+. Задача предполагает ввод текстового запроса от пользователя и обращение через API к некоторому сайту с целью получения списка возможных адресов соответствующих запросу и дальнейшего выбора одного из предложенных вариантов. По ТЗ интерфейс должен быть максимально userfriendly, поэтому я хочу реализовать управление с помощью клавиш Up, Down, Enter, Escape.
На данный момент я нашел библиотеку, которая решает мои проблемы в полной мере, она называется npyscreen

[image: Меню npyscreen]
[image: Подменю npyscreen]

Как видно в этой библиотеке нативно реализована функция back для возврата в предыдущее меню. Библиотека базируется на одной из стандартных библиотек с названием curses.
Вопрос состоит в том как реализовать back из подменю в приведенном ниже коде, документацию к curses.panel читал, пытался использовать функцию panel.bottom_panel() для возврата предыдущей панели, но получаю None. Ещё есть несколько вариантов кода для создания меню на базе curses ни в одном из них не смог реализовать функцию back. Хочу понять как нужно это сделать. Ломаю голову несколько дней уже. Код меню на npsycreen вот здесь [Меню npyscreen](https://github.com/npcole/npyscreen/blob/master/EXAMPLE-Menus.py).

Код, в котором хотел бы реализовать функцию back из submenu. [Взят отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14200721/how-to-create-a-menu-and-submenus-in-python-curses)

```
import curses
from curses import panel

class Menu(object):

    def __init__(self, items, stdscreen):
        self.window = stdscreen.subwin(0,0)
        self.window.keypad(1)
        self.panel = panel.new_panel(self.window)
        self.panel.hide()
        panel.update_panels()

        self.position = 0
        self.items = items
        self.items.append(('exit','exit'))

    def hide(self):
        self.panel.hide()
        panel.update_panels()
        curses.doupdate()

    def navigate(self, n):
        self.position += n
        if self.position < 0:
            self.position = 0
        elif self.position >= len(self.items):
            self.position = len(self.items)-1

    def display(self):
        self.panel.top()
        self.panel.show()
        self.window.clear()

        while True:
            self.window.refresh()
            curses.doupdate()
            for index, item in enumerate(self.items):
                if index == self.position:
                    mode = curses.A_REVERSE
                else:
                    mode = curses.A_NORMAL

                msg = '%d. %s' % (index, item[0])
                self.window.addstr(1+index, 1, msg, mode)

            key = self.window.getch()

            if key in [curses.KEY_ENTER, ord('\n')]:
                if self.position == len(self.items)-1:
                    break
                else:
                    self.items[self.position][1]()

            elif key == curses.KEY_UP:
                self.navigate(-1)

            elif key == curses.KEY_DOWN:
                self.navigate(1)

        self.window.clear()
        self.panel.hide()
        panel.update_panels()
        curses.doupdate()

class MyApp(object):

    def __init__(self, stdscreen):
        self.screen = stdscreen
        curses.curs_set(0)

        submenu_items = [
                ('beep', curses.beep),
                ('flash', curses.flash),
                ('back',)
                ]
        submenu = Menu(submenu_items, self.screen)

        main_menu_items = [
                ('beep', curses.beep),
                ('flash', curses.flash),
                ('submenu', submenu.display)
                ]
        main_menu = Menu(main_menu_items, self.screen)
        main_menu.display()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    curses.wrapper(MyApp)
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас "exit" как раз и работает как "back". А ошибка от того что в кортеже с back нет обработчика. Если переписать вашу обработку enter, получится то что вам и надо

```
import curses
from curses import panel

class Menu(object):

    def __init__(self, items, stdscreen):
        self.window = stdscreen.subwin(0,0)
        self.window.keypad(1)
        self.panel = panel.new_panel(self.window)
        self.panel.hide()
        panel.update_panels()

        self.position = 0
        self.items = items
        self.items.append(('exit','exit'))

    def hide(self):
        self.panel.hide()
        panel.update_panels()
        curses.doupdate()

    def navigate(self, n):
        self.position += n
        if self.position < 0:
            self.position = 0
        elif self.position >= len(self.items):
            self.position = len(self.items)-1

    def display(self):
        self.panel.top()
        self.panel.show()
        self.window.clear()

        while True:
            self.window.refresh()
            curses.doupdate()
            for index, item in enumerate(self.items):
                if index == self.position:
                    mode = curses.A_REVERSE
                else:
                    mode = curses.A_NORMAL

                msg = '%d. %s' % (index, item[0])
                self.window.addstr(1+index, 1, msg, mode)

            key = self.window.getch()

            if key in [curses.KEY_ENTER, ord('\n')]:
                if self.position == len(self.items)-1:
                    quit()
                    break
                else:
                    if len(self.items[self.position])==1: # without handler
                        break
                    self.items[self.position][1]()

            elif key == curses.KEY_UP:
                self.navigate(-1)

            elif key == curses.KEY_DOWN:
                self.navigate(1)

        self.window.clear()
        self.panel.hide()
        panel.update_panels()
        curses.doupdate()

class MyApp(object):

    def __init__(self, stdscreen):
        self.screen = stdscreen
        curses.curs_set(0)


        submenu_items = [
                ('sub_beep', curses.beep),
                ('sub_flash', curses.flash),
                ('sub_flash2', curses.flash),
                ('sub_flash3', curses.flash),
                ('back',)
                ]
        submenu = Menu(submenu_items, self.screen)

        main_menu_items = [
                ('beep', curses.beep),
                ('flash', curses.flash),
                ('submenu', submenu.display)
                ]
        main_menu = Menu(main_menu_items, self.screen)
        main_menu.display()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    curses.wrapper(MyApp)
```

Comment: В кортеже back специально не дописал обработчик потому что не знал что туда написать. Попробовал использовать ваш обработчик нажатия Enter, при вызове от кортежа состоящего из одного элемента получаю TypeError 'str' object is not callable из той строки, что после break, которая по логике должна отрабатывать только в случае кортежа из 2 элементов

Comment: в submenu_items надо так и оставить ('back',) иначе он считает что в кортеже не один элемент и пытается выполнить второй элемент (который как я понимаю вы вписали строковым)

Comment: Да действительно забыл об этой особенности кортежей. При запуске через PyCharm теперь получаю 'Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)' уже сталкивался с этой ошибкой ничего вразумительно не удалось выяснить что это и почему. В терминале выбрасывает из программы полностью, как по quit, только с задержкой в несколько секунд.

Comment: в ответе полностью пример вставил

Comment: Абсолютно идентичное поведение с полностью вашим кодом

Comment: в linux нормально. вод windows действительно есть проблема